# Determine if Apex is invoked via Visualforce

Tags: apex, pagemessages

I have a wrapper around a third party integration that I am invoking in two places -- a Visualforce page with user entered data, and a batch job that executes scheduled tasks every so often. I had originally placed some Apex messages in this code to display on the VF page prior to refactoring it to be used in both locations, but noticed that if I ran the same code from a scheduled job I received an error about adding messages outside of Visualforce invoked code.

The code is pretty simple:

```
ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, e.getMessage()));
```

And this is the error:

```
10:53:36:535 FATAL_ERROR System.FinalException: ApexPages.addMessage can only be called from a Visualforce page
```

I'm curious if there is a better way to check for this than:

```
if (ApexPages.currentPage() != null) { ... }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You also have System.isBatch() which returns a boolean.

Or you could consider refactoring and having one function which you call from VF, which then calls another function which does all the hard work. You can then handle the errors differently depending on the top level function, if that makes sense>
?

Comment: I agree with the refactoring, that is probably the best solution to extract that functionality into something called via different wrappers. Just curious if there was something less ugly -- System.isBatch() seems like a good solution, though there is likely other opportunities in Apex code that aren't batch where this could occur i.e. future methods from a trigger or something

Comment: The refactoring is your best solution.  The error message and whatever else your function is currently doing are distinct functionally.  Make the core function just do the core stuff, the visualforce controller then has it's own function which calls the core (good to be [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)), and based on the response from the core function decides whether it adds a page message.  Doesn't seem ugly to me

Comment: @MichaelWelburn You might also want to consider embracing the EAA Pattern called Service Layer, as described in this article. http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Apex_Enterprise_Patterns_-_Service_Layer

Comment: I think you may actually want System.isScheduled() here.  I'm looking at a similar situation where the code is definitely scheduled, but isn't batched.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not currently a direct supported way to determine if you're page is running in a visualforce context.  You're current solution `if(ApexPages.currentPage() != null)` seems like the ticket.

That said, refactoring as @Doug_B suggests seems like the correct solution from a coding design perspective.